# Implementing a help system for a Python3 desktop app

Tags: windows, osx, python, desktop-client

Basically, I am looking for recommendations on an end user help system for a Python3 desktop app that will fit the requirements below:

- Programmatically access a specific help page from the app
- Be end user searchable
- Windows and Mac OS
- Doesn't require the end user to install a reader
- Not too complicated to implement or package with the app

This desktop app is being migrated from VB.NET which had used a CHM file.  I do have the original HTML files that went into it.  I had considered just calling up the needed HTML page, but there are a lot of pages and it is helpful if the user has the ability to search for specific content.

This is my first app in Python, so I have no experience with compatible help systems.  I am also a complete noob when it comes to the Mac OS.

I understand that Sphinx is a possibility, but wanted to see what other options that may also be suitable.